# Is it possible to have an interactive div that does not change as the user navigates to other pages of the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I wanted to try making a website that had a sort of radio feature at the bottom of the page. And I wanted the user to be able to freely navigate through the website while that radio remained with them, not interrupting the song at all, as they clicked through different pages. The radio would also have a "song selector" feature so the menus would need to stay in the same place too. Is this possible? I'm guessing not, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

edit: I'm also thinking of a similar feature but for YouTube videos. Like a div that plays YouTube videos that stays with the user as they navigate through the website.

Comment: You need to use ajax to not reload all the page.

Comment: You could have your web pages loaded in iFrame and the player out side the iframe. As a side effect user will not be able to view the exact URL of the internal page!! Anyhow it is possible in this method.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into both methods. I'm happy to hear it is possible! I consider this question now solved.